# iOS XMPPFramework registerWithPassword ERROR

Tags: ios, frameworks, xmpp

I have a Problem with the XMPP-Framework for iOS. Every Time I fire `registerWithPassword` Method i get an Error:

> "Error Domain=XMPPStreamErrorDomain Code=1 "Please wait until the
>   stream is connected." UserInfo=0xad7c300
>   {NSLocalizedDescription=Please wait until the stream is connected.} "

I do the following steps in my Code:

```
 -(void)createUserWithUsername:(NSString*)name andPW:(NSString*)pw{

[self setupStream];
NSLog(@"name: %@ ",name);

NSString *nameFor = name;
[self disconnect];

NSString *jidBenutzer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@my-Server.com",nameFor];
NSError *error = nil;

NSError * err = nil; 
NSLog(@"jabberid : %@",jidBenutzer);
XMPPJID *jid = [XMPPJID jidWithString:jidBenutzer];
self.xmppStream.myJID = jid;


[[self xmppStream] registerWithPassword:pw error:&err];


NSLog(@"Connection: %@",error);

NSLog(@"Register: %@",err);
}
```

I hope you can help me !

Comment: From the error description: **Please wait until the stream is connected** - I would guess you are trying to login, when there is no connection. Are you sure your connection is working?

Comment: Hey if i register a User with username directly on the Server and then use the username and password in my app the connection works.

Comment: @rollerückwärts did u find any solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

From your example code, I do not see any call to:

```
[xmppStream connect:&error]
```

From the error message, you are actually not connected.

Make sure you correctly call the connect method and that you are processing the error accordingly.

Comment: Hey I unable to connect `xmpp` to `openfire`. How did you connect it? Can you please help me doing this? I have been searching for this for a week,but not getting any solution. Please help with the code snippet. I have also posted question 1 week ago.Please check my code here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26750301/connect-openfire-server-to-xmpp-framework-ios

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * This method attempts to register a new user on the server using the given username and password.
 * The result of this action will be returned via the delegate methods.
 * 
 * If the XMPPStream is not connected, or the server doesn't support in-band registration, this method does nothing.
 **/
```

This is the  below.

```
 - (BOOL)registerWithPassword:(NSString *)password error:(NSError **)errPtr
```

The method's instructions . You will find that before you use this method , you have to connecting the server.

I can' not find below.

```
   [xmppStream connect:&error]
```

I use the this.

```
   NSError *error;
   NSString *tjid = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"anonymous@%@", serverName];

   isRegister = YES;
   [xmppStream setMyJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:tjid]];

   [xmppStream connectWithTimeout:XMPPStreamTimeoutNone error:&error]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your openfire server is turned on from your system preferences.

Answer (score 0):

It is a late answer but still for any new developer like me: You have to login anonymously  before registration: For example you are login with yourname@yourserver and your password try to login with unknown@yourserver and for password put nothing. So it will connect the stream but will not authenticate this is required for registration. 
The stream should be connected but not be authenticated.