# Unable to connect XMPPFramework to Openfire server in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, openfire, xmppframework

I am working on an `iOS` chat app where user login to app. I've downloaded `XMPPFramework` from GitHub [XMPPFramework](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework). I am trying to connect `XMPP` framework with `Openfire` server by following [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-xmpp-setup--mobile-7190). Here is my code to connect XMPP to openfire.

```
- (BOOL)connect {

    [self setupStream];
    [xmppStream setHostName:@"192.168.1.5"];
    [xmppStream setHostPort:5222];

    NSString *jabberID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"userID"];
    NSString *myPassword = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"userPassword"];

    if (![xmppStream isDisconnected])
        return YES;

    if (jabberID == nil || myPassword == nil)
        return NO;

    [xmppStream setMyJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:jabberID]];
    password = myPassword;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![xmppStream isConnected])
    {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                            message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Can't connect to server %@", [error localizedDescription]]
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

The problem is when I run the app, it shows the alert `can't connect to server`. I have checked many questions on StackOverflow and tried googling but couldn't find any relevant solution. How to connect it to the Openfire serve? If I am doing anything wrong in my code please suggest me with a snippet of code or a tutorial to make this happen.

Answer (score 2):

A host of possibilities.

Try adding break points at `xmppStreamDidConnect` and `xmppStreamDidAuthenticate`.

If `xmppStreamDidConnect` isn't reached, the connection is not established; you've to rectify your hostName.

If `xmppStreamDidAuthenticate` isn't reached, the user is not authenticated; you've to rectify your credentials i.e. username and/or password.

One common mistake is omitting of `@domainname` at the back of username i.e. `username@domainname` e.g. `keithoys@openfireserver` where domain name is `openfireserver`.

Comment: Done with this. But How to send,receive and accept friend request with XMPP ?

Answer (score 2):

Hope this still relevant, if not, hopefully it will help others.
There are some issues with your code:

1. I don't see the call to connect, you should add something like this:

   ```
   NSError *error = nil;
   if (![_xmppStream connectWithTimeout:XMPPStreamTimeoutNone error:&error]) { 
       UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error connecting"
                                                           message:@"Msg"
                                                          delegate:nil
                                                 cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                 otherButtonTitles:nil];
       [alertView show];       
   }
   ```
2. Most of the XMPP API is asynchronous.
   You have to set the stream delegate in order to receive events.
   Check out `XMPPStreamDelegate` and `XMPPStream#addDelegate`

If you don't want to go through the code yourself [XMPPStream.h](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/blob/master/Core/XMPPStream.h)
, you can implement all methods of `XMPPStreamDelegate` and log the events. This will help you understand how the framework works.

Hope this helps, Yaron